# Need correct wording for scope method seeking specific wording in the object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, named-scope

I cannot figure the correct wording for this scope method. The task is to create a scope method that specifies the requests(which have notes) to display only the requests with the word "kids" in the note .  I can't seem to get the right wording for this to work

I have tried `scope :requests_with_kids_in_note, -> { where('note').includes(text: "kids")}`

`scope :requests_with_kids_in_note, -> { select('note').where('note').includes(text: "kids")}`

error messages aren't helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very easily through scopes, but you should format the where clause differently. Also I'd advise to make it more generic:

```rb
scope :note_contains, -> (word) { where('note LIKE %?%', word) }
```

And use it like this:

```rb
Model.note_contains('kids')
```

Comment: Hey thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: happy to help you! Any time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arel` to compose that query.

Assuming that you have a `Request` that have a `has_many :notes` association, you can write the scope like this:

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :notes

  scope :with_kids_in_note, -> {
    joins(:notes).where(Note.arel_table[:content].matches('%kids%'))
  }
end

class Note < ApplicationRecord
  # In this model, i'm assuming that "content" is the column
  # in which you have to find the word "kids".
  belongs_to :request
end
```

Comment: Good point on that this could be a 1:many relationship... I'm having some doubts whether it actually is the case in this question. But that's up to the TS to decide.

Comment: Thank you. Note is actually a param, this is also very educational. Thank you